# Reboot / shutdown safely with command line

Tags: shutdown, reboot

What is the proper command to shutdown or reboot the system safely? Is there a way to achieve this without invoking `sudo`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using KDE 16.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of options availabe, the easiest I have found for shutdown is `sudo poweroff` and for restart is `sudo reboot`. In general you will need to root privileges to perform these commands (security control - prevents users from bringing a system down without privilege escalation) although if you really tire of typing sudo every time, you can create aliases `vim ~/.bashrc_aliases` and add `alias poweroff="sudo poweroff"` and `alias reboot="sudo reboot"`. You can substitute `vim` with your favorite editor.

**Edit:** It was pointed out to me that the Desktop versions of Ubuntu 16.04 or greater no longer require `sudo` to perform these commands, however the Server versions do. Thank you Zanna for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @Zanna I think that's only for the desktop version. For the server version I've always needed `sudo`. I should have specified.

Comment: Is it less safe or less good to use `sudo shutdown` for shutdown? Do these use TERM signal to terminate processes before shutting down?